# How to get status code in http request in Angular2

Tags: http, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a http request and after that return the response object or bool. Doesn't realy matter which one. But i'm can't catch the error. I have a handleError function, but it does not realy work.

My code now looks like this.

The service

```
updateProduct(product: Product): Promise<number> {
        return this.http.put('/api/products/1' + product.id,product)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.status)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        //console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
```

The save function

```
onSave(): void {
    this.productService.updateProduct(this.product)
        .then(() => this.goBack())
        .catch(er => console.log(er));
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: so you are getting `4xx` status code in response ?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't really work." Keep in mind, you can use the same handler for both success, and failure. You just send it different information based on which response (success or fail) you get. In that handler you can set whatever you want based on that information. So if the handler gets "error", return this, otherwise return that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i see you're returning error.message when it exists

`return Promise.reject(error.message || error);`

Return whole `error` object instead of just `message` if you want to manipulate with that.

`return Promise.reject(error);`